# Div não se ajusta à tela

Tags: jquery, css

Na página

http://funerariasaopedro.net.br/

Faço uso do **plugin** **aos animate** https://michalsnik.github.io/aos/

Então a disposição das `divs` fica assim por padrão

```
<div class="aos-item" data-aos="fade-down">
  <div class="aos-item__inner">
      <img src="_img/bemVindo.png" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Enquanto o **site** estiver em **tela** grande **beleza**.

Mas quando estiver para celular uma das `divs`, que não consigo identificar qual é, fica com a altura (`height`) muito extensa.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Gostaria de fazer com que a `div` tivesse a altura do seu interior!

Como fazer isso para telas menores?

Mas o problema é que não consegui identificar onde alterar!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seu problema é que vc está usando um `line-height` na versão Mobile que está muito grande. no seu @media faz uma regra para remover esse `line-height`. Veja abaixo na imagem para ver como eu corrigi o bug.

**OBS:** Veja no painel do Chrome DevTools que eu retire da `.aos-item__inner` o `line-height: 260px;`

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: era o bendito line-height. Retirei, tudo ok. O brigado!